# Can a galaxy s6 fit a s6 edge case?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a galaxy s6 and I love it I do, but,  all of the cases that I like are for the edge and I don't really like that many I see for my phone. I like the glittery cases and all of them say for a galaxy s6 edge.  Could I fit my old s6 into one of these cases?

Answer (score 0):

[Different dimensions](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/size#/phones/size/Samsung-Galaxy-S6,Samsung-Galaxy-S6-edge/phones/8997,9193) (height and width). The part reserved for the edge on S6E will also bring trouble for S6. Don't bother.